# laravel shareable form URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to find a way to create a shareable form URL where I can use it to send it to the client(no authentication needed) and the client can fill the form and submit and it would show in my database. My problem with this is not creating the form my problem is how can I create a new shareable form URL that is unique and can only be used once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

1. In your table that will hold form submissions, create a string column `token` (or something similar) that is not nullable. Make the columns that will hold the data from the form submission all nullable. Also create a nullable timestamp column `completed_at` (or something similar) that will track if/when the client completed the form.
2. Create a new route that accepts `{token}` in the path as a route parameter. When this route is hit, your controller should validate the `token` matches an existing record in your table AND that the `completed_at` column is null (i.e. the form hasn't been submitted yet).
3. To make a new form available for the client, create a new record in your table that has only `id`, `token`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` populated. Use `\Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString()` to get a unique value for the `token` column. Then format a URL that uses the new token as a route parameter and send that URL to the client (e.g. `yourdomain.com/some-route/6df1be42-63ea-4c8a-ba3b-81ed93f4fee0`)
4. Upon client submission of your form, populate the data for the record in your table with the matching UUID (`token`) and set the `completed_at` timestamp to `now()`. Redirect or return a "thank you" page to the client.

Notes:

- The same thing could be accomplished with a sufficiently long random string instead of a UUID.
- You may also want to make the links expire by adding an `expires_at` timestamp column to your table. When the route for your form is hit, validate the `expires_at` timestamp is in the future. This also gives you the ability to "revoke" the link by setting the `expires_at` column to `now()` (as opposed to just deleting the record, so you still maintain a historical reference).